# I can't seem to change the max height of my container

Tags: css

[image]
I can't seem to change the max height of my container.

I think the container is not showing up at all, but I can not figure it out.

I can't seem to change the max height of my container. I think the container is not showing up at all, but I can not figure it out.

```css
     *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif; 
    }
    
    body{
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .container{
        position: relative;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        max-height: 100px;
        background: white(0, 0, 0);
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        box-shadow: 0 35px 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.103);
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .container .left_side{
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgb(87, 120, 158);
        padding: 40px;
    }
    .container .right_side{
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 40px;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <title>Yasef Ahnaf CV</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left_side"></div>
            <div class="right_side"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you're not sure if the container is showing up you can add this CSS to `.container`  

`border: 1px solid red`. It will add a 1px red border to it so it should be noticeable

Comment: I've edited the outcome screenshot. I want my container to appear as a box but it appears as a line instead?

Answer (score 0):

The height of a  container will expand to cover all of its contents and children elements.

If the content is smaller than the maximum height, the max-height property has no effect.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got it figured out now.

Comment: Great! Glad you did!

Answer (score 0):

Because the two divs inside are of less height.
You can change the max-height in the container.
To make the max-height effective you should make the two divs larger.

max-height: 100px; // --> height: 100px;